# how to set title within content page asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created a Content Page using Master Page.

Within Master Page, I have created the following tag for Title:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />   
</head>
```

Within Content Page, following are set:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["PatientRegistrationKey"]))
        {
           // ....
        }
        else
        {
            this.Page.Title = "My New Title";
            //....
        }
    }
```

Though I am also setting the Master Page at run time as bellow:

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["PatientRegistrationKey"]))
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/A.master";
        else
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/B.master";
    }
```

While getting open this page in browser, I got following Title:

***`http://localhost:3562/?PatientRegistrationKey=0` - My New Title***

Please advice for the changes, so that there should be only ***My New Title*** within title, nothing extra like query string etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you setting the title in the first if condition...?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't set a default title on the page, the page will show the URL as the title.
Go set the page title in the `.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="..."
    AutoEventWireup="true" Title="My Default Title" %>
```

Comment: I also set the Title within the Content Page also within <%@ Page... directive. There is the same problem.

Comment: It must be happening in some code you left out. There's no indication in your question of what it could be.

Comment: Is there any further suggestion?